# RxJava + Retrofit + Realm is doing unlimited get request

Tags: java, android, realm, retrofit

I am completely new to rxJava and it's really confusing, I want to make my app offline first and I've decided to use Realm and Retrofit, First I want to get the data from retrofit and then get the data from my remote webservice then, use realm's `insertOrUpdate` to merge the remote objects with the local one. I'm able to get on this process so far but when I looked into my Network requests on stetho, this method is complete requesting infinite times. Where did I go wrong? Here's the function

```
public Observable<RealmResults<Event>> all() {
    Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();

    return realm.where(Event.class).findAllAsync()
            .asObservable()
            .filter(new Func1<RealmResults<Event>, Boolean>() {
                @Override
                public Boolean call(RealmResults<Event> events) {
                    return events.isLoaded();
                }
            })
            .doOnNext(new Action1<RealmResults<Event>>() {
                @Override
                public void call(RealmResults<Event> events) {
                    service.getEvents()
                            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                            .subscribe(new Action1<List<Event>>() {
                                @Override
                                public void call(final List<Event> events) {
                                    try(Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance()) {
                                        realm.executeTransaction(new Realm.Transaction() {
                                            @Override
                                            public void execute(Realm realm) {
                                                realm.insertOrUpdate(events);
                                            }
                                        });
                                    } // auto-close
                                }
                            });
                }
            });
}
```

and here's the function on my activity, where I use it

```
private void getEvents() {
    Log.i("EVENTSELECTION", "STARTING");
    repository.all()
            .subscribe(new Subscriber<List<Event>>() {
                @Override
                public void onCompleted() {
                    Log.i("EVENTSELECTION", "Task Completed");
                    swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(Throwable e) {
                    Log.e("EVENTSELECTION", e.getMessage());
                    swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                @Override
                public void onNext(List<Event> events) {
                    Log.i("EVENTSELECTION", String.valueOf(events.size()));
                }
            });
}
```

Thank you so much.

Comment: I have a feeling that `onCompleted` is not called...

Comment: I don't understand why you made a cold observable out of a hot observable. You have a database that gives you change notifications, why are you ignoring it?

Comment: @EpicPandaForce sorry I'm new to rxjava and don't know about hot and cold observables yet, but I'm digging every possible resources now so I can learn. Thank you so much

Comment: Hot Observables never call onComplete because they will always emit events. Typical of anything that is listener based, for example a click listener, a change listener, text change listener and so on. Writing `.first()` here is like listening to only the first button click, the first letter pressed in an edit text, and so on. It doesn't really make sense to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Where did I go wrong?

Let's go through it:

> 1.

```
public Observable<RealmResults<Event>> all() {
    Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
```

This opens a Realm instance that will never be closed. So your Realm lifecycle management is wrong, refer to the [documentation for best practices](https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#controlling-the-lifecycle-of-realm-instances).

> 2.

```
return realm.where(Event.class).findAllAsync()
        .asObservable() // <-- listens for changes in the Realm
// ...
        .doOnNext(new Action1<RealmResults<Event>>() {
            @Override
            public void call(RealmResults<Event> events) {
                service.getEvents() // <-- downloads data
                        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                        .subscribe(new Action1<List<Event>>() {
```

You basically say that "in case there are any changes made to data in Realm, then download data from the service and write it into the Realm"

Which will trigger the RealmChangeListener which will trigger a download and so on.

This is a conceptual error, you're using [Realm notifications](https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#notifications) incorrectly.

---

`RealmResults<T>` is not just a list of objects, it is also a subscription for changes. So you need to keep it as a field reference, and "stay subscribed to changes in the database".

```
RealmResults<Sth> results;
RealmChangeListener<RealmResults<Sth>> changeListener = (element) -> {
    if(element.isLoaded()) {
        adapter.updateData(element);
    }
};

void sth() {
    results = realm.where(Sth.class).findAllSortedAsync("id");
    results.addChangeListener(changeListener);
}

void unsth() {
    if(results != null && results.isValid()) {
        results.removeChangeListener(changeListener);
        results = null;
    }
}
```

In your case, `RealmResults<T>` which symbolizes a subscription and also provides access to the current/new data is wrapped as an `Observable<T>` which you can create subscribers to.

```
Observable<List<<Sth>> results;
Subscription subscription;
Action1<List<Sth>> changeListener = (element) -> {
    if(element.isLoaded()) {
        adapter.updateData(element);
    }
};

void sth() {
    results = realm.where(Sth.class).findAllSortedAsync("id").asObservable();
    subscription = results.subscribe(changeListener);
}

void unsth() {
    if(subscription != null && !subscription.isUnsubscribed()) {
        subscription.unsubscribe();
        subscription = null; 
        results = null;
    }
}
```

As you can see, you have a subscription at the start of the component, and an unsubscription at the end of the component.

Calling `Observable.first()` is incorrect, it does not make sense to do that. If you saw it in any tutorial (I've seen it before...), then that tutorial was wrong.

Comment: yeah I've seen it on tutorials and stackoverflow answers, thank you so much for clearing it out to me, I removed my usage of observable notifications on realm and just simplified my solution like, get the local data on realm first then, fire a GET request using retrofit with observable and when something is returned from that request, I will insert or update the data to realms, even if the retrofit wont fire because of `no internet connection` I can still get the cached data. Thank you so much for clearing out.

Comment: You'll still need to observe changes made to the data in Realm via the RealmResults change listener (or as Observable) because RealmResults is a proxy view that changes in place.

Comment: I will try and practice your answer, thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

So it's really a `by design` on realm and it won't call the onCompleted, I added a `.first()` at the end of my `getEvents` function to get only the first result.

Comment: To get `onCompleted()`, instead of using `asObservable()`, you'd just need `Observable.just(results)`, but generally that's not something you need.